# Validation Always Tells There Is an Open DIV

Tags: validation

The Validator will just not accept my website and is always telling me, there are two errors:

```
1. an open DIV ("inhalt")
2. an article left
```

... and I just can not find the errors in the index.php.

Validator with exact error message: http://goo.gl/U2a8zs

index.php:

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<h2><?php _e('Journal'); ?></h2>

<div id="inhalt">

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="beitrag">
            <article <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3 class="gross"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <h4><?php the_time('F Y'); ?></h4></a>
            <div class="beitragsinhalt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <div class="normalmoduscontent"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail( 'blogbild' );} ?></div>
            <div class="mobilmoduscontent"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail( 'blogbildmobil' );} ?></div>

            <?php // if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail( 'blogbild' );} ?></a></div>
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="clearer"></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php postnavigation(); ?>

        <div class="clearer"></div>

<?php else : ?>

    <h3><?php _e('Nothing found','html5reset'); ?></h3>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php // get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see, I have closed div id=inhalt, but it says, I did not. You can see the website here: http://goo.gl/LUCb6P

Comment: You're looking at code for the Journal page, but referring to validation errors on the home page.

Comment: Nope, this is the standard site, the index.php. Journal will be only shown, if there are posts.

Comment: Look at the code you provided in your question. Line 5.

Comment: Damn it ... I mixed index.php for posts with page.php for fixed pages. Thank you. Do you want to put your answer as a reply, so I can rate and vote-close it? Thank you.